# Rickshaw AJAX with two endpoints

Tags: ajax, d3.js, rickshaw

So I have a working graph with Rickshaw and a single AJAX endpoint, the output of which I format like so:

```
onData: function(data) {
    var arrData = [];
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        var rawdata = {x: moment(item.timestamp).unix(), y: item.value};
        arrData.push(rawdata)
    });
    return [{name: 'Temperature', color: 'steelblue', data: arrData}];
},
```

I ideally want to pull another data series in here, but this one is accessible from a different data URL endpoint. Is there a way to successfully do this, or should I override the AJAX calls to get the data series myself, and then load up a Rickshaw graph from this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Rickshaw doesn't support multiple `dataURL`, see [the code](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/master/src/js/Rickshaw.Graph.Ajax.js). I would suggest loading the data yourself and providing it as is or, ideally, modifying your backend to perform only one request (much better for performance reasons).